# Dynamical updating of base class methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Let the class DivStr be based on class str.

```
class DivStr(str):

    def init(self, val):
        self.str_val = val
```

In str there are MANY methods but all of them are returning string type. What can I do to make all base string methods work the same like in string class but to make them return DivStr class.

For example if I am calling lower from string "abs" I will get string "ABC".
I need to get DivStr("ABC"). And it should be ok for all the str methods.
I have only heard about exec where I can do something like

```
  exec("def " + fun + "(*args): return DivStr(function(\"" + fun + "\", *args)"))
```

But I do not know how to iterate through all the str callable methods and how to add them with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dir()` to extract the names of the attributes of the class, `getattr()` to get the actual attribute and `callable()` isolate the attributes that are actually methods, e.g.:

```
for attr_name in dir(my_class):
    attr = getattr(my_class, attr_name)
    if callable(attr):
        ...
```

Note that using `exec()` combined with the above may be considered bad practice.